# Solving model in Python with pyomo or ipopt causes RuntimeError or "No executable found"

Tags: python, solver, pyomo, glpk, ipopt

I'm trying to solve a small optimization problem using pyomo but it doesn't work...

When I try:

```
opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')
```

I get the following Error:

> RuntimeError: Cannot write legal LP file.  Objective 'obj' has nonlinear terms that are not quadratic.

And when I try to solve the model with ipopt the following Error shows up:

> pyomo.common.errors.ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'ipopt'

When I check with help (ipopt) everything seems to be fine:

```
Help on package cyipopt:

NAME
    cyipopt - cyipopt: Python wrapper for the Ipopt optimization package, written in Cython.

DESCRIPTION
    Copyright (C) 2012-2015 Amit Aides
    Copyright (C) 2015-2017 Matthias Kümmerer
    Copyright (C) 2017-2021 cyipopt developers
    
    License: EPL 1.0

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    ipopt_wrapper
    scipy_interface
    tests (package)
    utils
    version

FUNCTIONS
    set_logging_level(...)
        Set the logger verbosity to the specified level.
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        level : int
            The verbosity of the logger. This threshold is used to determine which
            logging messages are logged by this module's :func:`log` function.

DATA
    SCIPY_INSTALLED = True

VERSION
    1.1.0
```

Here is the full code:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import ipopt

help(ipopt)
help(ipopt.problem)
help(ipopt.minimize_ipopt)

#Space      x     y    z
space = [2100, 650, 700]


model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# variables 1
model.a1 = pyo.Var(bounds=(0, 5), initialize=1)
model.a2 = pyo.Var(bounds=(0, 5), initialize=1)

# variables 2

model.bat1L = pyo.Var(bounds=(300, 1200), initialize=301)
model.bat1B = pyo.Var(bounds=(300, 1200), initialize=301)
model.bat1H = pyo.Var(bounds=(300, 1200), initialize=301)

model.bat2L = pyo.Var(bounds=(300, 1200), initialize=301)
model.bat2B = pyo.Var(bounds=(300, 1200), initialize=301)
model.bat2H = pyo.Var(bounds=(300, 1200), initialize=301)

# Constraints

model.con1 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.bat1L <= space[0])
model.con2 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.bat1B <= space[1])
model.con3 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.bat1H <= space[2])

model.con4 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.bat2L <= space[0])
model.con5 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.bat2B <= space[1])
model.con6 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.bat2H <= space[2])

model.con7 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.bat1L * model.a1 + model.bat2L * model.a2 <= space[0])

# Maximize the Volume inside the avaliable Space
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=model.bat1L * model.bat1B * model.bat1H, sense=-1)


opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')
results = opt.solve(model) # solves and updates model
pyo.assert_optimal_termination(results)
model.display()
```

Comment: do not `import ipopt`.  glpk cannot solve the problem as formulated because you have a 3rd order term in the obj.  `ipopt` should work, so delete the import statement, and just replace 'glpk' in the solver factory with 'ipopt'.  If that doesn't work, go to a terminal prompt and type 'ipopt' and you should get something if it is recognized, which it needs to be in order to do this.  Also, print your `results` and read them.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Just changing 'glpk' by 'ipopt' leads to an Error:
pyomo.common.errors.ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'ipopt'
WARNING: Could not locate the 'ipopt' executable, which is required for solver

There must be a problem with the conda ipopt installation I guess. But where do I start to fix the Problem?

Comment: did you remove the `import ipopt` statement?  did you try to execute ipopt from the command line?  How did you install ipopt?  if you have mac, you can homebrew install it

Comment: yes I removed the "import ipopt" statement. 
I'm using Win10 and Pycharm with Python 3.8
Wehn I type 'ipopt' into the Python Console without importing it i get a NameError: name 'ipopt' is not defined
I installed ipopt with the following conda comands:
conda install -c conda-forge ipopt
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 ipopt
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 ipopt
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 ipopt

Comment: Well, ipopt is not installed completely or correctly...  I'm not a pro on that, so you prolly need to Google or search that.  Remember:  after any install, you need to close/reopen terminal and restart any python processes to see the result.  (better yet, log out/back in).  `ipopt` needs to be recognized as a command for your program to work

Comment: When I try to solve the Problem with 'cyipopt' I get the following Runtime Error: "An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.This probably means that you are not using fork to start your child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module" How can I solve this?

Comment: There are also Ipopt binaries for Windows attached to some Ipopt releases at https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/releases

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `glpk` as an argument at `SolverFactory`, altough GLPK is consider much simpler and more efficient than ipopt, the last one is more flexible though, this issue is more likely to be related to the installation of ipopt, I highly recommend using the installed suggested by @stefan.